# partial global hegemony

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, comprehension

"Global" and "partial" seem to be contradicting to one another. What does
"partial" mean in this context?

> China's international leadership would bear little resemblance to the forms exercised by previous global leaders; exercising a **partial global hegemony** centered principally on Eurasia, the Middle East, and Africa, Chinese international leadership would be characterized by a reliance on finance, diplomatic engagement, and security assistance to exercise influence while maintaining a modest overseas military presence.

[Rand Corporation](https://www.rand.org/pubs/research_reports/RRA447-1.html)

Comment: I have adjusted your question. In the future, please use block quote for quotes, and not to state the question. Also, please source your quote.

Comment: I've even found 'Generalized partial global planning' (GPGP) on the internet. // Perhaps leaders in matters of trade, but not in terms of military might?

Comment: The hegemon extends beyond China, hence it is global. But not the whole globe.

Comment: It's like a whole wheat bread made with 100% whole grain plus white flour. Is it whole wheat? Yes. Is it partial whole wheat? Yes.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat 'Global' and 'extending beyond China' are hardly synonymous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: *Global hegemony* is a political term.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat In that case this question is probably off-topic, belonging under the terminology tag of Politics.SE.

Comment: According to Tinfoil Hat, 'Global hegemony' is a political term. and the usual definition of 'global' may thus not apply (the hegemony then not being 'global' in the everyday sense). But the term is then better researched on Politics.SE.

Comment: The terminology used to discuss China’s world status and objectives is part of everyday modern English, whether or not it is a specialty of particular entities. RAND’s article is meant for an informed general readership and thus should not be casually ignored or sent off to another site.

Comment: *Intercontinental hegemony* might have been a more accurate choice (or *nearly global hegemony* possibly).

Comment: @DjinTonic: I agree that there may be better choices; "transnational" is often used in this context. But when when "they" say "global," they mean — more or less — that the hegemon has spread beyond the country, aiming for domination.

Answer (score 0):

> What does "partial" mean in this context?

It means exactly what you imagine it to mean

OED:

**Partial (adj.)**

> **2.a. Relating to or involving a part of something rather than the whole; not general or total; constituting only a part; incomplete.**
>
> 1912   B. Russell Probl. Philos. xiii. 212   We suggested that there might be two kinds of self-evidence, one giving an absolute guarantee of truth, the other only a partial guarantee.
>
> 1956   I. Murdoch Flight from Enchanter iii. 29   He was embarrassed by his partial baldness.